# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'r.urlTree')

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm getting an error reported sometimes in my Angular 6 application. I get the information from my `ErrorHandler`, and posted to an error database. All I can get from the error stack belongs to the `vendor` or the `polyfills` bundles, and I cannot reproduce it on the same device. Any idea what can it be about? Has someone experienced anything similar?

```
{
        "agent": "OS: Mac OS X 10.15.0 | Browser: Safari 13.0.1 | Device: Other 0.0.0",
        "message": "undefined is not an object (evaluating 'r.urlTree')",
        "name": "TypeError",
        "stack": [
            {
                "columnNumber": 426011,
                "lineNumber": 1,
                "fileName": "https://www.myapp.com/vendor.19003f536e32efb3f8e2.js",
                "source": "https://www.myapp.com/vendor.19003f536e32efb3f8e2.js:1:426011"
            },
            {
                "fileName": "[native code]",
                "functionName": "forEach",
                "source": "forEach@[native code]"
            },
            {
                "columnNumber": 425926,
                "lineNumber": 1,
                "fileName": "https://www.myapp.com/vendor.19003f536e32efb3f8e2.js",
                "source": "https://www.myapp.com/vendor.19003f536e32efb3f8e2.js:1:425926"
            },
            {
                "columnNumber": 319818,
                "lineNumber": 1,
                "fileName": "https://www.myapp.com/vendor.19003f536e32efb3f8e2.js",
                "functionName": "onInvoke",
                "source": "onInvoke@https://www.myapp.com/vendor.19003f536e32efb3f8e2.js:1:319818"
            },
            {
                "columnNumber": 3531,
                "lineNumber": 1,
                "fileName": "https://www.myapp.com/polyfills.e7eccfefd953dba9834b.js",
                "source": "https://www.myapp.com/polyfills.e7eccfefd953dba9834b.js:1:3531"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Comment: if it is inconsistent there is no way of knowing. If you can isolate an environment for some beta users deploy the app unminified might log more insights.

Comment: The only consistency I've found is that all clients were either iOS (running Chrome or Safari) or Mac Os (always running Safari)